# How to push/notify client on new data in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Let's say I get data from a database or api. I have a nodejs server which allow me to get that data from those database or api via an endpoint. I have a client(reactjs) that gets the data and display on the screen.

How can I update my client when ever there is new data available?
I'm not looking for continuous ajax request.

Comment: I think you're looking for [`socket.io`](https://socket.io/).

Comment: yes but how do i make the server send event "whenever" there is new data?

Comment: you can read it up i the socket.it documentation

Comment: You can use socket protocol, when server have new data, server will push a           message to client (attach data or not). Or your client  can make a ajax request with very long timeout, in server side will keep this request (maybe in a array or map) when server have a "notify", server response to request has been stored(longpulling idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is detecting when the data changes have occurred so you can broadcast a general event to all connected clients.

Usually the api that makes the data update is the same api that needs to broadcast the event.

Imagine we have three client apps connected, via a socket, to the server api: app-1, app-2, app-3:

1. app-1 makes a data update via the api
2. The api performs the update and, on success, broadcasts a `data updated` event to all connected clients
3. app-1, app-2 and app-3 *all* receive a `data updated` event and react accordingly.

If the data update is made independently of the your api, via an external data-api for example, then things get more complicated:

- *You have control over the source code of data-api*

  You can create a socket connection between your api and the data-api. When the data-api detects a data change it sends a `data updated` event to your api. This event is then relayed by your api to the connected clients as described above.
- *The data-api is third party that you have no control over*

  Your only option is to regularly poll the data-api from your api and, when a change is detected, broadcast the `data updated` event to all the connected clients. Whilst this solution involves polling, it is both performant and scalable because it only involves a single, regular call from your api regardless of how many clients are connected.

Comment: well the update will be independent of any client interference. Think of a database or api that is being updated by someone else. What i am trying to do is get that updated data everytime it changes or theres new data to show

Comment: that someone else is not from my application, could be anyone in the world

Comment: Is the database api third party or do you have control over its code? What database is being used here?

Comment: for now i am using mongo db but later on i wont be having any control on that because i will get data from an api

Comment: see edited answer for some more detail on your options